# How to deal with trolls?

Tags: discussion

Maybe this happens to every site. Sooner or later comes a troll and starts posting unrelated, obnoxious, arrogant, insulting or simply unreadable content. Is there anything we can or should do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely don't let bad content go. :)

- Posts that are simply arrogant but otherwise correct can be downvoted or edited to improve the tone.
- Insulting posts should be flagged. There's an "it is not welcome in our community" flag:

  > **it is not welcome in our community**
  >
  > This answer contains content that a reasonable person would consider offensive, abusive, or hate speech.

  A few of those from different community members will delete the offending answer without moderator involvement.
- Unreadable posts can be flagged as "very low quality" or using the "other" flag reason so you can leave a note explaining what's going on.

If the user's misbehaving across multiple posts, feel free to just flag one of them and leave an explanation for a moderator to look at. Moderators can delete posts and warn/suspend the user if needed.

I took care of the specific incident that spawned this question. If anything like that happens again, flag away! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many things you can do depending on the situation. If you're sure it's a troll, flag one post as an example (the admins will look into the other posts as well).

Use the appropriate flag, but if you use the `spam` flag, be careful: it's very powerful. :) If enough spam flags are given, the flagged user will get a -100 reputation punishment (I'm not sure about other things).

I think in this case, you could flag/vote to migrate the question to Meta (you can flag to migrate if you don't have enough rep to vote to close).